# Why Python is not responding "windows can try to restore the program. If you restore or close the program, you might lose information."

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I am using python 3x in Jupyter notebook, what I want to do is to plot some of the R plots in a shell in jupyter notebook. However, the problem is that when I do so, the plot is drawn on another window rather than in the shell. However, when I close it the jupyter notebook gives me an error a "Dead Kernel"

[image]

My code is:

```
# To fit a restricted VAR model we will have to call the function from R

# Call function from R
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

# Calling packages
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

# Test for serial correlation
MTS = importr("MTS", lib_loc = "C:/Users/Rami Chehab/Documents/R/win-library/3.3")
RMTSmq=MTS.mq

# Create data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((108, 2)), columns=['Number1','Number2'])

# Test for data
RMTSmq(df, adj=4)
```

After I close the program I am getting this

[image]

Can someone help me? I wish if I may plot the graph inside jupyter notebook if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another answer for the above question using precisely the arguments raised in the above question. Rather the flavour

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro, pandas as pd, numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

# Call function from R
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri import numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

# To plot drawings in R
grdevices = importr('grDevices')

# Save the figure as Rami1.png
grdevices.png(file="Rami1.png", width=512, height=512)

# We are interested in finding if there is any serial correlation in the Multivariate residuals
# Since there is a fitting VAR it will be cumbersome to create this function here therefore consider 
# that residauls resi as follow
resi = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((108, 2)), columns=['Number1','Number2'])

# firt take the values of the dataframe to numpy
resi1=np.array(resi, dtype=float)

# Taking the variable from Python to R
r_resi = numpy2ri(resi1)

# Creating this variable in R (from python)
r.assign("resi", r_resi)

# Calling libraries in R for mq to function which is MTS
r('library("MTS")')

# Calling a function in R (from python)
p = ro.r('result <-mq(resi,adj=4)')    
grdevices.dev_off()

from IPython.display import Image
Image("Rami1.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank my great friend Sarunas for his wild idea. In particular, he informed me that there is a way out through "instead of showing the picture (in the window) you could try to write it as png or another image format? Then open it with some photo viewer? "

That is exactly what I have done!
Consider for example that I would like to show a figure from R say the plot of sin(x) from x=-pi till 2pi

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

grdevices = importr('grDevices')


grdevices.png(file="Rami1.png", width=512, height=512)
p = ro.r('curve(sin, -pi, 2*pi)')    
grdevices.dev_off()
print()

from IPython.display import Image
Image("Rami1.png")
```

The output is
[image]